# Function not returning

Tags: php, function

```
function checkSessionToken($token) {
  if (!isset($_SESSION['token']) || empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
    return false;
  }

  return $token == $_SESSION['token'];
}
```

For some reason this function is not returning any value, while it really should, causing my script to fail. When I put the result in a variable and echo it, I don't get any output. Why is this?

Thank you

Comment: this looks like it should work fine. Try putting die('test'); at the top, and see if it is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks good.

Don't `echo` the value. Use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). `echo false;` does not output anything ([example](http://codepad.org/1sT2WylA)).

`var_dump` will output `bool(false)`.

Comment: Thank you, after about 45 minutes, I finally found a stupid mistake in my script. It wasn't something in this function anyway.

Answer (score 1):

*`return $token == $_SESSION['token'];`* may return *NULL* if there is no return value because of one of your data. You can check it with *`print gettype(checkSessionToken($token));`*.
To avoid this you could make sure to return the bool result of (foo == bar), e.g. adding parenthesis as per follow:  *`return ($token == $_SESSION['token']);`*